# How can I get Insights data for Instagram Media posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-insights

I have tried all possibilities to get insights for a media post posted in instagram. 
That's the post which I am trying to get insights for- 
`https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BUs4jxfAtIs/`

Clearly [endpoints provided by instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) are not sufficient to get any kind of insights data.

And when I try graph api 
`v2.9/1525843122691691052_5512691375/insights`
I receive an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 1525843122691691052_5512691375",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "A64kR4gnbfC"
  }
}
```

Is this even possible? Has anyone been able to do this? The documentation does not help much and looks like not to be up to date.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and I'm not sure how to get it to work either.

Comment: As a quick check, I'm assuming your media object conforms to their note in the docs: `Story insights are only available for stories that are active at the time of the request, even if you have enabled 14-day story retention via the app.`  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, not that this would cause the error you showed, but I noticed you're not sending the required `metric` parameter, unless you just left that off the URL.

Comment: I have the same error when using the FB instagram `/MY_MEDIA_ID/comments` endpoint. Whereas using the Instagram api gives me the expected results back

Comment: Got this working: first get the media ids via FB endpoint `/insta_business_id/media` This gives other instagram media ids?? When using a media id returned by this and now using it in FB endpoint  `/media_id/insights...` does give results back